# How to have dimmed content on Semantic UI React (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, semantic-ui

Im having a problem on implementing dimmed content on semantic ui react sidebar on nextjs...

This is the dimmed content on semantic ui
[image]
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/#states-dimmed

this is my layout code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CartSidebar from './CartSidebar';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const StoreLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const [toggleCart, setToggleCart] = useState(false);
  function toggleMenuCart() {
    setToggleCart(!toggleCart);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <CartSidebar toggleMenu={toggleCart} />
      <Navbar onToggleMenuCart={toggleMenuCart} />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default StoreLayout;
```

this is my navbar code:

```
  <nav>
   <div className="borderLeftList">
    <li className="cart">
     <Button
       onClick={props.onToggleMenuCart}
       className="cart-icon empty"
     />
    </li>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

this is my sidebar code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function CartSidebar(props) {
  const classes = cn(
    'ui',
    'sidebar',
    'push',
    'right',
    'inverted',
    'menu',
    'vertical',
    'animating',
    { visible: props.toggleMenu }
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Menu.Item as={Link} href="/admin">
        <a>
          <i className="fa fa-home" />
          Dashboard
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>

      <Menu.Item as={Link} href="/admin/orders">
        Second Menu
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item as={Link} href="/admin/products">
        Third Menu
      </Menu.Item>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my _app.js code:

```
   <StoreLayout>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
   </StoreLayout>
```

if you need any more details you can ask on the comment... Thank you so much in advance!!! :)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain to people what "dimmed content" means, I have no idea.  Also if you're using CSS then show it.

Comment: no its actually a option on semantic ui

Comment: I Edited thanks for telling me

Comment: The documentation only refers to Pusher being dimmable, but you are not using the pusher component.

Comment: oh so its not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation shows it will dim all of its children:

```
<Dimmer active={true} page>
  <ChildComponent/>
</Dimmer>
```

Which will then dim the child component.  Along with that you can also specify properties like "page" to tell it to dim the whole page.

If you're trying to use it with sidebar, then you have to wrap the content for sidebar in a dimmer.

```
const Page = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

  return <div>
    <Sidebar setActive={setActive}/>
    <Dimmer active={active} page> // this is a child
      <Content/>
    </Dimmer>
  </div>
}
```

Then in the sidebar you'll have to set the active when you click an item or whatever.  This example isn't perfect, just gives you a rough idea of what you can do.

Alternatively:

```
.dimmed {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

You can also just do it yourself and apply a class with opacity to whatever needs to be dimmed.

Comment: yes but the problem is how am i gonna make it child component

Comment: It is a child, see updated answer, I commented that it's a child already.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: i get what your trying to say... but i cant implement the active and i dont have a Dimmer package or file or something...

Comment: wait is the dimmer your talking about, this one: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer/#types-dimmer ?

Comment: Yes.  You can just import it.

Comment: oh thanks i think i know what to do... well explained ill let you know once i tried it :)

Comment: i tried my best but i coudnt make it I WAS SO NEAR THO

Answer (score 0):

CREDITS ON @Matriarx for giving me idea on how to answer his question...

You have to import the Dimmer on sematic-ui-react and then parent the child using this code:

```
 <Dimmer.Dimmable dimmed={toggleCart}>
        <Dimmer
          className="dimmedContent"
          active={toggleCart}
          onClickOutside={handleHide}
        />
```

put this on your css so that you can give yourself a style, without this css you cant make the dimmed fullscreen

```
.dimmedContent {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) !important;
  cursor: default !important;
  z-index: 8 !important;
}
```

this is the full code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dimmer } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import CartSidebar from './CartSidebar';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const StoreLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const [toggleCart, setToggleCart] = useState(false);
  function toggleMenuCart() {
    setToggleCart(!toggleCart);
  }
  const handleHide = () => {
    setToggleCart({ active: false });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Dimmer.Dimmable dimmed={toggleCart}>
        <Dimmer
          className="dimmedContent"
          active={toggleCart}
          onClickOutside={handleHide}
        />
      <CartSidebar toggleMenu={toggleCart} />
      <Navbar onToggleMenuCart={toggleMenuCart} />
      {children}
      </Dimmer.Dimmable>
    </>
  );
};

export default StoreLayout;
```

also dont forget to put the css that i provided above :)

Cheers!